# What is mom-pkin?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, metaphors

My bae asked me about the meaning of *mom-pkin* in the book she's reading. I'm stunned and google searching produced but acronyms and chemical stuff. The full sentence is as follows.

> She still had ninety minutes before she turned back into a *mom-pkin*. With a flirty toss of her head, she threw back the last of her drink and smiled at Lee.

Does it actually mean anything in general? As far she could tell, there's no specific property in the regarded person that she could point to as a possible meaning. Is it something like getting from a *girly, frivolous type* and back to a *mom'ish, responsible* one? What on Earth is the *pkin* suffix?

*Additional definition:* bae (or possibly BAE, as it's an acronym, stands for [Before Anyone Else](https://www.google.se/search?q=definition+bae&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=BdjAWa_nD4HHsAGZr6XYCg)). This information's been added because many people asked about what it means.

Comment: Great question!  I imagine that for most native speakers the *-pkin* portion (from *turn into a pumpkin*) will be easier to understand. Explaining the *mom* part, well, an answer probably can guess, but it'd be easier with more context.  Could you tell us where this quote is from?

Comment: @snailplane [*All I Ever Wanted* by Lucy Dillon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/All-Ever-Wanted-Lucy-Dillon/dp/1444796046)

Comment: "My bae"? - who?

Comment: @Therkel Does it matter who she is? I just wrote *bae* instead of *significant other* or *live-in girlfriend* for convenience's sake. It could as well say *someone who isn't a registered member of ELL nor has a feasible ability to become one* but it'd be cumbersome.

Comment: Sorry, no, it does not matter. I had never come across the word before so I was just curious. Thanks for the clarification, though.

Comment: @Therkel Oh, I see. I learned it a few months back - apparently it's huge amongst certain internet communities (in my case, [the best time thief ever](http://9gag.com)).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In the popular Cinderella fairy tale, a fairy turns the poor and dirty Cinderella into a princess and a pumpkin into the carriage that will get her to the party she wants to attend.

The spell, however, has a time limit: it will end at midnight.

What happens then is that the carriage **turns back into** a pumpkin.

The word *mom-pkin* is a wordplay on the original story. The mom will *turn back into* a regular, boring *mom* once the time limit (90 minutes) has passed. So, the author thought that the Cinderella fairy tale was famous enough to take the same sentence and change *pum* into the similar-sounding *mom*, turning a pumpkin into a *mompkin* (which is not a real word).

The hyphen just makes it easier to spot the intent of the substitution. It serves a visual cue and it carries no grammatical meaning.

Comment: While similar to another existing answer, I tried to explain the wordplay and the similarities between the situations more toroughly.

Comment: +1 for "the dash just makes it easier to spot the intent of the substitution".

Comment: Since the OP tried to look it up in a thesaurus, I think it's also worth noting that the word is **not real**. It's implied above, but not totally explicit.

Comment: Since the author appears to be British, I wonder if the original text was *mumpkin* - a native Br.E reader might have appreciated the substitution without the (rather forced, IMHO) hyphen cue?

Comment: Funny anecdote about this phrase being used in weird ways: People at my workplace will say "John is about to turn into a pumpkin" to mean John (or whomever is named) has a meeting they have to leave for really soon so we have to wrap things up.

Comment: Very good answer. I'll speculate a bit further, although more story context would help: seems likely to me that the woman in the story is a (presumably) single mother who found the chance to doll herself up for a date (or to go bar hopping), something she rarely has time or opportunity to do. 90 minutes might be when the babysitter has to leave, or when a child's nap is expected to be over, and she has to resume her typical "mom" role.

Answer (score 17):

In storytelling contexts, the words **turned back into a** will be, nine times out of ten, an allusion to the fairy tale known as *Cinderella*.

If you do an ngram search for `turned back into a *`, **pumpkin** is very high on the list.  At the stroke of midnight, the magical carriage in that tale turns back into the pumpkin from which it is made. The heroine is partying at a ball at the  castle, where she hopes to encounter her Prince Charming. She too will transform, back into a drudge.

The suffix of **pumpkin** is actually **-kin**. It is a diminutive.  {noun}-*kin* is a "little"  {noun}. NOTE:  **pkin** is not a *bona-fide* morphological suffix here but simply an allusion to the *spelling* of the word *pumpkin*, so that the word **pumpkin** will come to mind, and summon up the Cinderella story where, at the stroke of midnight, the female heroine's magical carriage turns back into a pumpkin and she herself turns from party-girl back into drudge.

P.S. Since @Lawrence asks "If pumpkin is the little guy, what's the big version :)"

If I were to answer Lawrence's jest, I'd say the big guy is occupied by Peter Pumpkin-Eater's wife.  But seriously, diminutives can express both *appreciation* (tenderness, affection) and *depreciation* (irony, disparagement, derision—the idea that something is inferior).  The pumpkin was regarded as fodder and as a rather crude food for humans, or as food for rather crude humans.

I should add that it is not always clear to native speakers that -kin is a diminutive.  For example, a "manikin", a shop-window display dummy, is more-or-less life-size (though usually not realistically so), and few native speakers recognize the -kin as a diminutive there. Though since the dummy is only a dummy, no more than a basic human shape, often lacking hands and feet, the diminutive could be understood to mean "a lesser human", "a mere human shape". More importantly, unlike cognate *-chen* in German, *-kin* is not very productive in Modern English; that is to say, relatively few words get formed with it.

Comment: I generally agree, the only problem seems to be here that it was Cinderella's paraphernalia turned back into a pumpkin, she was not. Then, it's either a bad metaphor or an author's exploitation of both pumpkin/bumpkin at the same time.

Comment: @Mv Log: I think you're being too literal-minded. Allusion doesn't have to establish a perfect correspondence: `a:b :: c:d` in all details. Allusion can simply evoke a context which is generally applicable to the narrated situation.

Comment: @MvLog You can call it a bad metaphor if you like, but the key point is that people *do* use it that way, and the goal here is to understand the patterns in how people use language.

Comment: The -***p**kin* suffix and the rhyming of *mum-pkin* with *pumpkin* suggest the imagery you describe. A *pumpkin* isn't a little *pump*, though.

Comment: @Lawrence: but it is.  Don't be misled by orthography. The "true" suffix (not the suffix as spelled here for the sake of the visual clue) is **-kin**.  The pronunciation of the word (*pun*-kin) goes back to a word of French origin.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo If *pumpkin* is the little guy, what's the big version :) ? Out of curiosity, I looked up the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pumpkin). It seems to indicate that the spelling is a phonetic alteration of an earlier spelling, rather than one with a *-kin* diminutive suffix.

Comment: @Lawrence: You are misreading that entry.  The *-kin* ending of "pumpkin" var. "punkin" is not derived from the *-ion* ending of *pompion*. The Oxford English Dictionary says "An altered form of *pumpion*, with the ending conformed to the suffix -KIN".  Compare *lambkin, bodkin, manikin*, etc.

Comment: The first half of this answer is solid, but the discussion of the -kin suffix distracting and irrelevant. The author of the original text is not using a suffix; "mom-pkin" is a portmanteau of "mom" and "pumpkin".

Comment: @Xerxes: the second half of the answer is responding to/correcting the OP's "What on Earth is the *pkin* suffix"  and responding to a comment by Lawrence.  The author's portmanteau use is further proof of what I said, that native speakers do not always recognize the -kin suffix for what it is.  That is hardly "irrelevant", but I'd agree to call it "tangential".  If you're "distracted" by it, that's on you.

Comment: @Xerxes: Maybe you think the suffix discussion is "distracting and irrelevant", but I find it at least as interesting as the original question.  Though I wonder if kin in pumpkin is a suffix - that is, added to some original pump-like root - or just a syllable?

Comment: @jamesqf "1640s, alteration of pompone, pumpion "melon, pumpkin" (1540s), from Middle French pompon, from Latin peponem (nominative pepo) "melon," from Greek pepon "melon," probably originally "cooked (by the sun)," hence "ripe;" from peptein "to cook" (see cook (n.)). ." http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pumpkin

Comment: @jamesqf As OP I need to point out that my intention was to merely get the meaning of the term. The mentioning of the suffix was nothing more but an attempt to help other help me combined with presenting a proof of self-effort. So for me, personally, the suffix matter is only a bonus. Nevertheless, I found it interesting, once it's come into presence.

Comment: Your digression on "-kin" could be misconstrued as claiming the original quote suggests the sentence's subject will become a diminutive, lesser, or endeared mom. "-kin" may be relevant to the etymology of "pumpkin" itself, but the only purpose of the letters "-pkin" in this sentence is to suggest the word "pumpkin" as a whole.

Comment: @MvLog It might not make a lot of sense, but the idiom "turn into a pumpkin" is in fact often applied to people.  At a party, I'll often hear someone say something like "I'd better get home before I turn into a pumpkin."

Comment: **pumpkin** - From Middle French pompon, from Latin pepō, from Ancient Greek πέπων (pépōn, “large melon”), from πέπων (pépōn, “ripe”), from πέπτω (péptō, “ripen”). Suffixed with the now obsolete -kin. **-kin** (now chiefly dialectal) Used to form adjectives expressing resemblance or likeness to, similar to -like. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pumpkin https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-kin

Comment: @CJ Dennis: So the -kin here is a suffix, but not the current diminuitive one.

Comment: @CJ Dennis: a related suffix, **kins**, is still quite productive.  *What shall we do tonight, babykins?  Dinner and a movie?*